Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Controller::getDepartments() C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo-crud-project\addForm.php on line 7
enter image description here
enter image description here

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Controller::getDepartments() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo-crud-project\addForm.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo-crud-project\addForm.php on line 7

addForm.php
<?php

$title = "แบบฟอร์มบันทึกข้อมูลพนักงาน";
require_once "layout/header.php";
require_once "db/connect.php";

$result = $controller->getDepartments();
print_r($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
<h1 class="text-center"><?php echo "แบบฟอร์มบันทึกข้อมูลของพนักงา"; ?>
    <form method="POST" action="showData.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fname">a</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Iname"> นามสกล</label>


Please dont make the title the error message, and Dont post pictures of code. Its text so post it as text

WHere do you instantiate the class onto $controller?

require_once "layout/header.php";
require_once "db/connect.php";
$result = $controller->getDepartments(); 
print_r($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>

@SAKDEE avoid including screenshots of code in your question. Instead, paste the actual code directly into the question.

Based on the screenshot you shared, it seems you haven't included controller.php in your code.
After the line require_once "db/connect.php";, please add the following line:
require_once "db/controller.php";

Note: I noticed in your screenshot that you have controller.php inside your db directory. Make sure you've used the correct path to the controller.php file.

getDepartments(); 
    print_r($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
 
?>
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Controller::getDepartments() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo-crud-project\addForm.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo-crud-project\addForm.php on line 7

@SAKDEE put controller.php code into question please

@SAKDEE also share connect.php in your question
